# Correct way to add attachment to email in magento 2.3.3+

Tags: magento2.3.3, email-attachment

From the release of new version of magento 2 come with some changes in code base
I can't add attachment to email anymore. My case used new TransportBuilder class extend from origin

> Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder

for send email
I have searched some tutorials or guide in google but seem all of them outdates now
Is there any best way to add attachment without impact other function ? No override approach allowed here

Answer (score 0):

Found this official answer from magento here
[https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Backward-incompatible-Changes-in-the-
Mail-Library-for-Magento-2/ba-p/144787](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Backward-incompatible-Changes-in-the-Mail-Library-for-Magento-2/ba-p/144787)